# How can I call boto.ec2.connect_to_region() with IAM:PassRole credentials?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I would like to run boto (2.38.0) on an EC2 instance. I would like to connect without specifying credentials -- the permissions available to boto are defined via an IAM:PassRole definition.

I already have aws CLI commands working on the instance (e.g. `aws s3 cp`). My problem is that calling `boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')` fails with this:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/get-attached-volume", line 5, in <module>
    c = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/ec2/__init__.py", line 66, in connect_to_region
    return region.connect(**kw_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/regioninfo.py", line 187, in connect
    return self.connection_cls(region=self, **kw_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 103, in __init__
    profile_name=profile_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 1100, in __init__
    provider=provider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.38.0-py2.7.egg/boto/auth.py", line 987, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129976/boto-issue-with-iam-role) seems to have the answer, but running [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130701/3904) from the command line gives me the same failure.

The answer there mentions not having "no other credentials are found in environment variables or in a boto config file". I haven't been able to find any such configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the policy associated with the user? I am guessing the user is allowed to pass the S3 role but not the EC2 role. That explains why the CLI works and boto/ec2. Or try this CLI command and see if it works:

```
aws ec2 list-regions
```