# AWS S3 bucket API calls using AWS IAM User Role credentials:

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, amazon-iam

The motivation behind using AWS IAM user roles is to have AWS automatically handle the AWS keys/credentials for each service call. This approach is being used behind Apache Camel, which then uses the credentials to do data transfers securely i.e. not storing any credentials within the source code.

The issue that I have found is the credentials that are made within the IAM tool work only within the aws cli.

For instance, I run this successfully with the auto-generated credentials from IAM (setting them within my environment variables):

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://x/test.txt
```

However, when I try to mimic the same operation (same credentials) within an API call, I am given this error message:

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;         
Request ID: 07A4FCDCA2E82F9E)
```

Additionally, using my AWS account security credentials (i.e. making a security key id and key), I can get the aforementioned API working. So the API is not the issue (considering I have tested 2 diatonic credential sets).

Lastly, my AWS IAM user role is set to have full access to S3 buckets and the S3 bucket itself is configured to allow for that. This is where I started to become lost on a potential route to take.

Knowing all of this, I have done some research and have found people with similar issues ([1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/issues/36)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129976/boto-issue-with-iam-role)). Each source presents different ideas to solve the problem, but neither seems applicable for my use case with Apache Camel.

For knowledge of my use of Apache Camel, my code example is as follows:

```
    String awsS3Connection = "aws-s3://x" + "?accessKey=" + accessId +
                             "&secretKey=" + accessKey;

    from(awsS3Connection)
            .to(importProcessingEndpoint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary credentials are meaningless to -- and unrecognized by -- the service APIs unless they are used in conjunction with their accompanying session/security token.

When a signed request is being prepared...

> You add the session token to an HTTP header or to a query string parameter named `X-Amz-Security-Token`. You add the session token to the HTTP header or the query string parameter, but not both.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#RequestWithSTS

However, from the Camel [docs](http://camel.apache.org/aws-s3.html), it's not obvious how to pass the token or whether they even implemented support for this.

Comment: I am coming towards the same conclusion that you have made about Camel's support of this. I will see if there is any implementation or lack of rules for passing custom credentials within the camel interface. Any additional information that I discover, will be posted as a separate answer and a comment under your answer!

Comment: It seems that the most recent aws sdk is not compatible with camel and therefore the credential retrieval works, but the client does not work with Camel.

Answer (score 0):

After thorough research, I have found this to be an issue with Camel not supporting the most recent version of the [AWS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html). It does successfully retrieve the credentials (see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#loading-credentials) documentation), but the client itself that is created breaks Camel.

The only solution that I could find was customizing the AWS SDK to return the credentials while it builds the client and then using said credentials to build a client that is compatible with Camel using an older version of the AWS SDK... Although this is very unpractical and necessary to include two versions of the same SDK, it can work.