# Connect to s3 bucket using IAM ARN in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to connect to s3 bucket using an IAM role.

My bucket name is: test-bucket
I have created a role by the name : **my_role_s3** and given it full s3 access (i.e., 'AmazonS3FullAccess')

When I am trying to access the name of the buckets using the code -

```
import boto3
import os
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://<username>:<password>@191.18.0.25:9400"
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "https://<username>:<password>@191.18.0.25:9400"
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
     print ("Bucket: %s" % bucket.name)
```

**I am able to connect** and get the bucket names. But for this, internally, boto3 is using the Access key. But I do NOT want to use access key and use IAM role for this.
So for IAM role, I am trying this code-

```
import boto3
import os
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://<username>:<password>@191.18.0.25:9400"
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "https://<username>:<password>@191.18.0.25:9400"
assumedRoleObject = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::824214495785:role/my_role_s3",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)
credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials']
s3_resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken'],
)
```

Now when the method - **sts_client.assume_role** is called, I get the error -

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::824214495785:user/testuser is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::824214495785:role/my_role_s3

Boto3 is using the user - **testuser**. Can you tell me what changes do I need in my code/account settings so that testuser is not used and the role is used or allow testuser to access sts:Assumerole?

Comment: Is the testuser given the IAM permissions to assume that role? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_roles.html#troubleshoot_roles_cant-assume-role

Comment: yes the permission is given to testuser

Comment: Is this running on premise or your laptop or on an ec2 server? Boto will automatically pull in the credentials from the instance role on ec2 is why I am asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129976/boto-issue-with-iam-role#11130701