# Uploading files to Amazon s3 bucket using ARN iam in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have been given a bucket name with ARN Number as below:

> arn:aws:iam::<>:user/user-name

I was also given an access key.

I know that this can be done using boto.

[Connect to s3 bucket using IAM ARN in boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296084/connect-to-s3-bucket-using-iam-arn-in-boto3)

As in the above link do i need to use 'sts'?
if so why am i provided with an access key?

Comment: The ARN you show is for an IAM User (not a bucket). You also state that you have an Access Key. You will also require a **Secret Key** (or Secret Access Key) that works similar to a password -- do you have this? With the Access Key and Secret Key, you will be able to make calls to the AWS APIs. Do you want to access S3 via the AWS Management Console, the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or programmatically?

Comment: Thank you so much John for the response.

Comment: If you can answer my questions, then we can tell you how to access S3.

Comment: I need to access access it programatically. Now I have been given the secret key as well. i want to run my python script and the file should be uploaded to S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend you install the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which provides a command-line for accessing AWS.

You can then store your credentials in a configuration file by running:

```
aws configure
```

It will prompt you for the Access Key and Secret Key, which will be stored in a config file.

Then, you will want to refer to [S3 — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) to find out how to access Amazon S3 from Python.

Here's some sample code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2') # Change as appropriate

client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

Comment: So don't i need to use the iam user anywhere?  I mean the arn number (arn:aws:iam::<>:user/user-name) ?

Comment: No. That is a unique identifier for your IAM User. However, the Access Key is already associated with your user, so the system can identify you purely from the Access Key.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch!